# Create reset filter button in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using a theme which has an ajax filter for the product category pages, and it works really well.

The only thing is that the button wish is displayed, when someone is selecting filters, don't reset them, it directs the visitor back to the shop page. How can I change the logic of the button, that it would just reset the selected filters? So that the users stay on the page where they are? Because right now the button makes no sense.

Thx so far.

**HTML**

```
<div class="nm-shop-results-bar  has-filters is-category">

    <a href="http://localhost/amaoni/" id="nm-shop-filters-reset" data-shop-url="http://localhost/amaoni/">
        <i class="nm-font nm-font-close2"></i>Filters active <span>(1)</span></a>
        <a href="http://localhost/amaoni/" id="nm-shop-search-taxonomy-reset" data-shop-url="http://localhost/amaoni/"
        <i class="nm-font nm-font-close2"></i>Showing <span>“Hundebetten”</span></a>
</div>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
/**
 *  NM: Shop - Results bar/button
 */

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

global $nm_theme_options;

$results_bar_class = '';
$results_bar_buttons = array();

// Filters
$filters_count = nm_get_active_filters_count();
if ( $filters_count ) {
    $results_bar_class = ' has-filters';
    $results_bar_buttons['filters'] = array(
        'id'    => 'nm-shop-filters-reset',
        'title' => sprintf( esc_html__( 'Filters active %s(%s)%s', 'nm-framework' ), '<span>', $filters_count, '</span>' )
    );
}

// Search
if ( ! empty( $_REQUEST['s'] ) ) { // Is search query set and not empty?
    $results_bar_class .= ' is-search';
    $results_bar_buttons['search_taxonomy'] = array(
        'id'    => 'nm-shop-search-taxonomy-reset',
        'title' => sprintf( esc_html__( 'Search results for %s&ldquo;%s&rdquo;%s', 'nm-framework' ), '<span>', esc_html( $_REQUEST['s'] ), '</span>' )
    );
}
// Taxonomy
else if ( is_product_taxonomy() ) {
    $results_bar_buttons['search_taxonomy'] = array(
        'id' => 'nm-shop-search-taxonomy-reset'
    );
    $current_term = $GLOBALS['wp_query']->get_queried_object();

    if ( is_product_category() ) {
        $results_bar_class .= ' is-category';
        $results_bar_buttons['search_taxonomy']['title'] = sprintf( esc_html__( 'Showing %s&ldquo;%s&rdquo;%s', 'nm-framework' ), '<span>', esc_html( $current_term->name ), '</span>' );
    } else {
        $results_bar_class .= ' is-tag';
        $results_bar_buttons['search_taxonomy']['title'] = sprintf( esc_html__( 'Products tagged %s&ldquo;%s&rdquo;%s', 'nm-framework' ), '<span>', esc_html( $current_term->name ), '</span>' );
    }
}

if ( ! empty( $results_bar_buttons ) ) :
?>

<div class="nm-shop-results-bar <?php echo esc_attr( $results_bar_class ); ?>">
    <?php 
        $shop_url = esc_url( get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'shop' ) ) );

        foreach ( $results_bar_buttons as $button ) {
            printf( '<a href="%s" id="%s" data-shop-url="%s"><i class="nm-font nm-font-close2"></i>%s</a>',
                $nm_theme_options['shop_filters_enable_ajax'] ? '#' : $shop_url,
                $button['id'],
                $shop_url,
                $button['title']
            );
        }
    ?>
</div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

I think that's the code part which directs the users to the shop page, but i don't know how to change it, so that it just reset the selected filters.

```
<div class="nm-shop-results-bar <?php echo esc_attr( $results_bar_class ); ?>">
    <?php 
        $shop_url = esc_url( get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'shop' ) ) );

        foreach ( $results_bar_buttons as $button ) {
            printf( '<a href="%s" id="%s" data-shop-url="%s"><i class="nm-font nm-font-close2"></i>%s</a>',
                $nm_theme_options['shop_filters_enable_ajax'] ? '#' : $shop_url,
                $button['id'],
                $shop_url,
                $button['title']
            );
        }
    ?>
</div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

***Javascript***

```
        if (self.filtersEnableAjax) {
            /* Bind: Results bar - Filters reset link */
            self.$shopWrap.on('click', '#nm-shop-filters-reset', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var resetUrl = location.href.replace(location.search, ''); // Get current URL without query-strings
                self.shopGetPage(resetUrl);
            });

            /* Bind: Results bar - Search/taxonomy reset link */
            self.$shopWrap.on('click', '#nm-shop-search-taxonomy-reset', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var $resetButton = $(this);
                if ($resetButton.closest('.nm-shop-results-bar').hasClass('is-search')) {
                    // Search
                    var urlSearchParam = self.urlGetParameter('s'), // Check for the "s" parameter in the current page URL
                        // Search from external page: Get default/main shop URL (current URL may not be the default shop URL)
                        // Search from shop page: Get current URL without query-strings (current URL is a shop URL)
                        resetUrl = (urlSearchParam) ? $resetButton.data('shop-url') : location.href.replace(location.search, '');
                } else {
                    // Category or tag
                    var resetUrl = $resetButton.data('shop-url'); // Get default/main shop URL
                }

                self.shopGetPage(resetUrl);
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: live example would be helpful, not everyone uses that

Comment: https://www.amaoni.de/shop/hunde/hundebetten/ That's the category page of the website.

Comment: now I don't understand the question, as button to reset filters is already there :)

Comment: yes, but it's directing the users to the shop page, and not just remove the filters and let them at the current open page and just remove the selected filters

Comment: That's because it's a link, not a button.

Comment: But it does the same when applying the filter, it's not using XHR (ajax) request

Comment: I updated the comment with the javascript code to it

Comment: and example site? could u update that in there as well? it's much easier to resolve problems on live examples

Comment: The code above is already on the website, wich i posted https://www.amaoni.de/shop/hunde/hundebetten/